# Multiple comparison and edit file

Tags: php, html, file, preg-match

Here is my `$file1` structure (there are thousands of like that groups):

```
Group   id_7653
{
    type    register
    sub_name    155
    1   3123    1   12  
    2   3124    1   8   
    3   3125    1   4   
    4   3126    1   12  
    5   3127    1   8   
    6   3128    1   4   
    .....
}

Group   id_8731
{
    type    register
    sub_name    155
    1   4331    1   12  
    2   4332    1   8   
    3   4333    1   4   
    4   4334    1   12  
    5   4335    1   8   
    6   4336    1   4   
    .....
}
```

And here is my `$file2` structure (again, there are thousands of defined values)

```
.....
3123    Spada+1
3124    Spada+2
3125    Spada+3
3126    Spada+4
3127    Spada+5
3128    Spada+6
3129    Spada+7
3130    Spada+8
.....
```

And here is my Worker script that makes, compares `$file1` and `$file2`.

```
<?php

//read the first file in as a string
$file1 = file_get_contents("dataparser\names1.txt");
//read the second file in as an array
$file2 = file("dataparser\names2.txt");

//index from file2 that we are going to build
$file2Index = array();

foreach($file2 as $line){
    //split the line
    $line = explode("\t", $line, 2);
    //validate the line, should be only 2 values after explode and first should be a number
    if(count($line) == 2 && is_numeric($line[0])){
        //add to index
        $file2Index[$line[0]] = $line[1];
    }
}

//now get all the values from file1 that we want (second column)
preg_match_all('/^\s*\d+\s*(\d+)\s*\d+\s*\d+\s*$/m', $file1, $matches);

$file1Values = array_unique($matches[1]);

//loop over the matches from column 2
foreach($file1Values as $value){
    //check if the key doesn't exist
    if(!isset($file2Index[$value])){
        //echo error message
        echo "Value {$value} does not exist in file2<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

What makes that script:

Compares `$file1` and `$file2` and shows me which values are not defined in `$file2`

So far, everything works okay.

I want to extend that my script a little bit, so I want to replace that {$value} with my `$file2` structure.
This time, I don't want to check that value, I want replace it directly from `$file1` value. (Spada etc...)
Which paths I should follow...? Can I get some examples please...

Comment: What format is that in `$file1` (and `$file2` for that matter)? Just made up formats?

Comment: they are just TXT files, just made it

Comment: I know they are text files. I mean the *formatting* of the text file (the way the text looks).

Comment: there are no spaces in both file, formatting was made with ONLY [TAB]

Comment: Do you know what JSON is?

Comment: Yes, I just heard it, but I don't know.

Comment: Okay. JSON is a *file format* that you can use to save data in a structured way, as text files. In JSON, an array looks like `["value1", "value2", "value3"]`. It is formatted in a certain way, so that you can recognize it as an array. Now, in `$file1`, what kind of *file format* are you using? Did you just make it up by yourself, or is it some kind of file format?

Comment: No, It's my special file format. Is there any way with PHP, I know there is a way with PHP but It's complicated.

Comment: Using a file format like JSON would make your life *much easier*. Making up your own file formats is rarely a good idea.